# LSF Job Routing Algorithm

Tags: lsf

I have a requirement where i need to restrict users into reusing the first 3 exec machine they  are using so as to reduce license usage of our tools.

So, lets say that at any instant an user is using 3 machine - mac1,mac2,mac3. Now if he is going to run a new job, he is expected to re-use one of the three machine already in use.

*Up to this point , I hope my requirement is clear. Please prompt me if you have any doubt*

**Now, I aim to design an algorithm which decides which is the best machine to use.
I need following input to design the algo:-**

**1. Among mac1,2,3 , what parameters can be used to decide what machine is best to exec a job.**

*There are few other requirements as well, but i would like to try and fail before posting them here. The one posted above is the biggest bottleneck i have*

Comment: I went through lsload command, but frankly I need some sort of guidelines to decide what load factors/user logins/memory/etc signals health of a exec machine.

Comment: Can you use a consumable numeric resource for the licenses, and then put that resource in the job resreq's order clause?

Answer (score 0):

LSF is often used on systems that support both interactive and batch users. On one hand, users are often concerned that load sharing will overload their workstations and slow down their interactive tasks. On the other hand, some users want to dedicate some machines for critical batch jobs so that they have guaranteed resources. Even if all your workload is batch jobs, you still want to reduce resource contentions and operating system overhead to maximize the use of your resources.
Numerous parameters can be used to control your resource allocation and to avoid undesirable contention.

Read more here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_admin/interactive_batch_jobs_tuning.html